# How to copy notes item using Java

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I would like to copy note item from one note document to the other using Java below is the my lotus script version of what i want to achive in Java

```
Sub CopyItem(FromDoc As NotesDocument, ToDoc As NotesDocument, itemName As String)

Dim FromItem As NotesItem
Dim ToItem As NotesItem

If Not (FromDoc.Hasitem(itemName)) Then Exit Sub
Set FromItem = FromDoc.GetFirstItem(itemName)
If Not ToDoc.hasitem(itemName) Then Set ToItem = ToDoc.CreateItem(itemName)
ToItem.Values = FromDoc.Values      
End Sub
```

I have tried the below:

```
 public static void copyAnItem(Document FromDoc, Document ToDoc, String sItemName){
        Vector<String> FromItem = new Vector<String>();
        Vector<String> ToItem = new Vector<String>();

        if(!FromDoc.hasItem((itemName))){
            return;
        }
     FromItem = FromDoc.getItemValue(itemName);
     if(!ToDoc.hasItem(sItemName)){
         ToItem.add(itemName);
        }


     ToItem.addAll(FromDoc);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void copyAnItem(Document fromDoc, Document toDoc, String itemName){
    try {
        if(fromDoc.hasItem(itemName)) {
            toDoc.copyItem(fromDoc.getFirstItem(itemName));
        }
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        // your exception handling
    }
}
```

You can get the whole item including all properties from fromDoc with [getFirstItem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETFIRSTITEM_METHOD_JAVA.html?lang=en) and can copy it to toDoc with [copyItem](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_COPYITEM_METHOD_JAVA.html) in just one line of code.

Comment: is it posible to create a new NotesItem() object in Java ? just like we do in lotus script-  Set holdinItem = New NotesItem(fromDoc,itemName,"")

Comment: Yes, you have pretty much the same Notes classes and methods available in Java like in LotusScript. When you open a LotusScript Notes class description in Notes help then you have links to related Java classes at the end of the document.

Comment: I tried to do a literal translation of @simonpeter's LotusScript syntax to Java, but I got stuck on the CreateItem call. It doesn't exist in the Java classes. But then I looked it up for LotusScript, and found that it doesn't exist there either! And there's no new Item() constructor in the Java classes either, so a direct translation of set holdinItem= new NotesItem(...) isn't available.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz use the keyword "new notesitem" to search the Notes help ist the first link u will see as Examples: NotesItem class

Comment: Yes, I know that new NotesItem() is supported in NotesItem class - for LotusScript. (What I was saying was that the LotusScript code in your question is calling ToDoc.CreateItem(), but there's no CreateItem call in the LotusScript classes.)  But more important to my point is that even though new NotesItem() is supported for LotusScript, there's no exact equivalent for the Java classes. You can search the documentation for the Domino Java classes for new Item(), and it's not there.The doc says that in Java code you need to use replaceItemValue() copyItem(), copyItemToDocument, etc.

Comment: There is, btw, a CreateItem method in the Notes C++ API, but that's a very, very different set of classes.

Comment: Haha, seems that's one of the rare pieces where we have a difference between LotusScript and Java. So, having a Notes client help to look up now, it's clear: there is no new Item(...) available in Java. Documentation http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESITEM_CLASS_JAVA.html?lang=en tells "To create a new Item object from scratch, use `replaceItemValue` in Document."

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void copyAnItem(Document FromDoc, Document ToDoc, String sItemName){

    if(FromDoc.hasItem(sItemName)){
        ToDoc.replaceItemValue(sItemName, FromDoc.getItemValue(sItemName));
    }    

}
```

It won't work with Authors or Readers items. Better the Knut solution :)